# If statement inside while loops not printing correctly

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, substring

I'm trying to compare a string, pass, to a dictionary file list.  If it directly matches a word, it is considered weak (balloon). If it contains the word from the dictionary file (#balloon232), it is considered moderate. If neither, its strong.  In this code, weak and moderate both work correctly, but when a strong pass is entered, it says it is moderate. Thanks for the help.

```
public static void passwordStrength(String pass, String file2) {
    boolean found2 = false;
    boolean found3 = false;
    try {
        y = new Scanner(new File(file2));
        z = new Scanner(new File(file2));
        while (y.hasNextLine()) {
            if (pass.equals(y.nextLine().trim())) {
                System.out.println("\nYour password is weak");
                found2 = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        while (z.hasNextLine()) {
            if (pass.contains(z.nextLine().trim()) && !found2) {
                System.out.println("\nYour password is moderate");
                found3 = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found3 && !found2) {
            System.out.println("\nYour password is strong");
        }
        y.close();
        z.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trimming the strings you read from the file, but not the variable `pass`.  Maybe `pass` contains leading or trailing blanks?  If `pass` were, say `"  pass   "` and a trimmed string from the file were `"pass"`, it wouldn't be an exact match, but it would be a "contains" match...

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems fine it should print password is strong.  You should print out all lines that you read in from the file to debug and see both when the password and the word from the file doesn't match.

I don't think it makes sense to create multiple scanners and read the file twice.  You can read in the file once and test the pass to see if it's a week or moderate and return the string and if not found return strong.  You can throw the exception so that main up to you.  Unless you specifically want to print out the password strength in this function.

Here is a sample.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordTest {
    public static String passwordStrength(String pass, String file2) {

        try {
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(file2));

            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String passInFile = fileScanner.nextLine().trim();
                if (pass.equals(passInFile)) {
                    return ("Your password is weak");
                }
                if (pass.contains(passInFile)) {
                    return "Your password is moderate";
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();

        }
        return "Your Password is strong";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(passwordStrength("test", "test.txt"));
    }
}
```